# Race queries in react with apollo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

I'm using `react-apollo` with the `graphql` HOC:
I have a search by user input query that can run for a variable amount of time and is invoked by key strokes, the result of this query is passed on to the UI component to show the search result.

1. (0:00) The user searches for `Foo` which takes 10s to run
2. (0:01) After 1s the user enters `Foo bar` which takes 5s to run
3. (0:06) The component renders with `Foo bar` results like the user would expect
4. (0:10) The first query for `Foo` finishes running and renders stale results for `Foo` though the input is now `Foo bar`

Is there any standard way of dealing with such scenarios?

My current solution would be implementing a HOC that would check if the `term` the user entered equals to the `data.variables` returned by the result and if there is a mismatch disable further rendering using `shouldComponentUpdate`. Still, would love to hear more opinions as this sounds like a common scenario in React.